# C#/.Net code analysis report by TFS reports or Cruise Control.NET

Tags: tfs, cruisecontrol.net, code-analysis

Can we do a code analysis report with the help of TFS reports ? If so can someone help me to configure a .Net code analysis report in TFS Reports or Cruise Control.Net with full details.

I have a project under TFS in location : $/{Team_Project}/{folder1}/{Project1}/{Project1.sln}.

I want to configure an analysis report on this project & e-mail this analysis report daily.

Comment: You need to specify what sort of analysis you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an automated build in TF Build to compile your code on a regular interval.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259687.aspx

You can then customise the build process to run any kind of code analaysis that you like. There is Static Code Analyis out of the box but many people integrate with something like sonar.

http://www.vlaquest.com/2013/08/how-to-integrate-sonar-with-tfs-part-1/

Out of the box TFS does Code Analysis and Code Coverage. The automated build will load the Code Coverage into TFS and make it available in the analysis cube. You can then create a custom report in reporting services that is emailed daily with some interesting metrics.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647430.aspx

I would recommend that you look at the Code Quality report.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380683.aspx

It really depends on the level of detail that you want and what ingight you are looking for.